# JavaScript create object/array with child arrays a smart way / duplicate PHP data structure in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Since I'm working a lot with PHP I need some advice. Currently, I'm working on an HTML / JavaScript AJAX sorting function for my UI. Sometimes an element can have some childs - sometimes not. To save the order at my PHP backend, I need a data structure in PHP which looks like this:

```
$test = [
    '20',
    '22',
    '24' => [
        '25',
        '26'
    ]
];

foreach ( $test as $key => $a ) {
    if ( is_array( $a ) ) {
        error_log('Key: ' . $key);
        error_log( print_r( $a, true ) );
    } else {
        error_log( $a );
    }
}
```

This way I can check if the value is an array to know if it has childs or not and access the parent one by the key which is null in every other case.

My only approach in JS is the following:

```js
let a = {};
let b = 2;
let c = 20;

a[c] = c;
a[b] = b;

let test = [2, 3, 5];

a[b] = test;

console.log(a);
```

I'm not very happy about the fact that the value is the key and the value sometimes a number and sometimes an array. Is there a better idea how to handle this?

Comment: I don't think this is option based since I'm not asking for A or B, I'm asking for a better way to create this structure in JavaScript since I'm lacking knowledge here. With my first PHP code I'm just showing the data structure I need. I'm not providing a second JS option to choose from.

Comment: Your `$test` from php is equivalent to js `[20, 22, {24: { 25, 26 }}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not clear whether you have an issue with the overall data structure (even in PHP) or with the way you have to replicate it in JavaScript. I will assume the latter.

Your JavaScript code is not entirely equivalent to the PHP one:

- in PHP you have an array at the root
- in JavaScript you have an object

I don't think you can have in JavaScript the same data structure actually. But you could use the [Array.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to obtain a better equivalent and not worry about the key.

```js
let a = [];
let b = '20';
let c = '22';

a.push(c);
a.push(b);

let test = ['25', '26'];
a.push({'24': test});

console.log(a);
```